# How to transmit Multipart file object into Spring web RestClient post method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, upload, rest-client, multipartfile

I have two microservices:

- One for user authentication (authentication microservice).
- One for handling video file storage (videoStore microService).

Process :

- ("/create") belongs to authentication microservice
- ("/create") is accessible only with well formed token (JWT).
- ("/create") receives multipartFile
- ("/create") sends multipartFile to storage service
- ("/uploadfile") belongs to file storage microservice
- ("/uploadfile") performs the storage of the file into linux filesystem
- 

```
@PostMapping(value ="/create")
 ResponseEntity<Response> createVideo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) 
 {  
    videoRestClientService.upload(multipartFile);
    return new ResponseEntity<Response>(new Response("video has been stored"), HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

- 

```
public Response upload(MultipartFile multipartFile){
    
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.create("http://localhost:8095");
    Response response = restClient.post()
     .uri("/uploadfile")
     .contentType(...)
     .body(multipartFile)
     .retrieve()
     .body(Response.class);
}
```

-> In videoStore microService

```
@PostMapping("/uploadfile") 
public ResponseEntity<Response> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {

    Response response = fileSystemStorage.storeFile(multipartFile);

    return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

- 

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Question :

- Is it possible to use restClient to post multipartFile ?

Remark :

- I don't have any getway implemented (don't have the skills yet).
- The authentication service is doing the getway job (to bad for clean archicture).